# Working with Fieldset class and ORM in FuelPHP

Tags: php, fuelphp

First : sorry for my long message.

I'm trying to learn Fuel, but I have some problems with Fieldset class and Orm.
I've create a Model which extends ORM, in order to get an automatic generated form, according to my database.

**My Model**

```
class Model_Product extends \Orm\Model
{
    protected static $_table_name = 'products';

    protected static $_properties = array(
        'id' => array(
            'data_type' => 'int'
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'data_type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'validation' => array(
                'required', 'trim', 'max_length'=>array(30), 'min_length'=>array(3)
            ),
        ),
        'description' => array(
            'data_type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Description',
            'validation' => array(
                'max_length' => array(290)
            ),
            'form' => array(
                'type' => 'textarea'
            ),
        ),
        'price' => array(
            'data_type' => 'integer',
            'label' => 'Price',
            'validation' => array(
                'required', 'trim', 'valid_string' => array('numeric','dots')
            ),
        ),
        'pic' => array(
            'data_type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Path to the pic',
            'validation' => array(
                'required', 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'registered' => array(
            'data_type' => 'date',
            'label' => 'Registration date',
            'validation' => array(
                'required', 'trim'
            ) //'valid_string' => array('numeric','dashes')
        ),
    );
} //end of class Model_Product
```

Then I create the controller which will validate the form.

**My function from the controller**

```
function action_add() 
{ 
    $fieldset = Fieldset::forge('add_product')->add_model('Model_Product')->repopulate();

    $form = $fieldset->form();

    $form->add('submit', '', array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 'Add item', 'class' => 'button-link' ));

    $validation = $fieldset->Validation();

    if($validation->run() === true) 
    { 
        $fields = $fieldset->validated();

        //create a new Product, with validated fields 
        $product = new Model_Product;

        $product->name = $fields['name']; 
        $product->description = $fields['description']; 
        $product->price = $fields['price'];
        $product->pic = $fields['pic']; 
        $product->registered = $fields['registered'];

        try 
        { 
            //if the product is successfully inserted in the database
            if($product->save()) 
            { 
                Session::set_flash('success', 'Product successfully added !');
                \Response::redirect('products/product_details/'.$product->id); 
            }
        } 
        catch(Exception $e) 
        { 
            Session::set_flash('error', 'Unable to save the product into the database !'.$e->getMessage()); 
        }
    } 
    //If the validation doesn't pass 
    else 
    { 
        Session::set_flash('error', $fieldset->show_errors()); 
    }

    $this->template->set('content', $form->build(), false);

} // end of method add()
```

My first question :
How and where in my function from controller can i add a 'fieldset' tag with a specific class, in order to 'beautify' my auto-generated form ?
Let's say

```
<fieldset class="add_product">
```

Second question :
What do I have to do in order to correctly validate de 'price' field, because in MySQL is set as decimal(5,2), but when I'm trying to validate with my actual validation rule, it doesn't pass (it works only with integer values Ex.: 42, but not with decimal Ex.: 42.35). I have tried to change the type from 'integer' to 'double', but it doesn't work .

If you can point to some specific documentation regarding my problems, which I possible didn't read yet, please do feel free.

Gabriel

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the first question To change the automatically generated form you will need to copy `fuel/core/config/form.php` to the `fuel/app/config` directory and edit this file to suit your needs.